# How can I check whether USB3.0 UASP (USB Attached SCSI Protocol) mode is enabled in Linux?

Tags: linux, usb, external-hard-drive, sata, uasp

I have a laptop running Ubuntu 15.04 (3.19.0-21-generic) and an external USB3.0 2.5" SATA HDD enclosure which claims that it supports UASP mode ([the S2510BPU33 model by StarTech](http://www.startech.com/uk/HDD/Enclosures/USB-3-SATA-III-Hard-Drive-Enclosure-UASP-Support~S2510BPU33)). I have no problems mounting the drive or reading/writing to it.

I'd like to be able to confirm the following:

1. That the device itself actually supports UASP
2. Whether my chipset also supports UASP
3. Whether the device is using UASP when I mount it

Whereabouts can I find this information?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you know the name of your device, find the USB Bus and Device numbers:

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 002 Device 005: ID xxxx:yyyy MyDeviceManufacturer
...
```

Then look at the USB tree and find your device (mine was Bus 2, Dev 5):

```
$ lsusb -t
...
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
...
```

You can see in my case the `uas` driver.

If UAS is not in use you would see `usb-storage` (like Dev 3 in my case).

Answer (score 17):

In addition to [the answer](https://superuser.com/a/930884/708661) austinmarton gave, you can run

```
lsusb -v -d VPID | grep -i interface
```

where VPID is the vendor/product ID reported in `lsusb`. For example:

```
$ lsusb -v -d 1234:5678 | grep -i interface
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
    bNumInterfaces          1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              6
```

Notice that the only `bInterfaceProtocol` value listed is `80 Bulk-Only`. This device would *not* be a UASP-configured device. However, if you see an additional `bInterfaceProtocol 98`, this *would* be a UASP-configured device.

These values are given in decimal, but the spec refers to them by their hex values...

```
50h (80d): USB Mass Storage Class Bulk-Only (BBB) Transport
62h (98d): Allocated by USB-IF for UAS.
```

This information can be found in the [Mass Storage Specification](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/Mass_Storage_Specification_Overview_v1.4_2-19-2010.pdf) on [usb.org](http://www.usb.org), section 3 Protocol Codes, Table 2 — Mass Storage Transport Protocol.

I'm not sure if this answers your first or second questions, though, since it's unclear if this value would be reported on both machines/devices that do support UASP and those that do not.

Answer (score 10):

To complete the answer:

If your controller does **not** support UAS, the linux kernel is kind enough to tell you so:

```
$ dmesg | grep "UAS"
[58669.959610] usb 4-2: USB controller 0000:03:00.0 does not support streams, which are required by the UAS driver.
[58669.959613] usb 4-2: Please try an other USB controller if you wish to use UAS.
```

Also, lsusb shows a line for bInterfaceProtocol 98, but it is empty:

```
$ lsusb -v -d 0080:a001 | grep -i interface
bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bNumInterfaces          1
  Interface Descriptor:
    bInterfaceNumber        0
    bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
    bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
    bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
    iInterface              0 
  Interface Descriptor:
    bInterfaceNumber        0
    bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
    bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
    bInterfaceProtocol     98 
    iInterface              0
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the presence of the bInterfaceProtocol 98 line indicates that this particular device supports the protocol required for UAS -- but the line is always "empty" (i.e. has no text description string) whether or not UAS is supported.  (In fact it's simply empty because no description for class 8/subclass 6/protocol 62 is given in /var/lib/usbutils/usb.ids , to go along with the description "Bulk-Only" given for protocol 50.)

Answer (score -3):

You must check whether [the UAS driver](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/storage/uas.c) is being used for your disk. First, identify the disk in question:

```
   # dmesg | grep sdb
   ...................
   sd 9:0:0:1: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

So my device is a SCSI disk. Here you find the information about the drivers currently in use,

```
   # ls /sys/bus/scsi/drivers
     sd  sr
```

So, in my case, the appropriate driver is either *sd* or *sr*. To check which one, I try

```
   # cd /sys/bus/scsi/drivers/sd/9:0:0:1
   #
```

Hence my driver is *sd*.You can double-check that the directory */sys/bus/scsi/drivers/sr/9:0:0:1* does *not* exist. Hence my external disk is not UASP.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct, the SD and SR drivers don't tell you about UAS. I've got a disk using UAS and it uses the SD driver (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/scsi/sd.c). Pretty sure the SR driver is for CD/DVD drivers (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/scsi/sr.c)

Comment: That's because sd/sr work on a different layer than uas/usb-storage.